# When I add the data object 'job', the error : vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "job" is not defined on the instance

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Why when I add some data object 'job', the vue is error....what should I do? The code like this

app.js :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: {
    name: 'My Name',
    job: 'My Job',
    age: 'My Age'
  }
})
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>VueJS Practice</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="vue-app">
      <p>{{ name }}</p>
      <p>{{ job }}</p>
      <p>{{ age }}</p>
 </div>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Are `{{ name }}` and `{{ age }}` displayed?

Comment: just `{{ name }}` is displayed because the `{{ job }}` is not displayed so `{{ age }}` not displayed too

Comment: Can you replicate this in a Codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

Data needs to return an object

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#vue-app',
  data: function () {
    return {
        name: 'My Name',
        job: 'My Job',
        age: 'My Age'
    };
  }
})
```